# How can I make a piece of code run before a component is Disposed?

Tags: castle-windsor

I am using the castle-windsor framework, and I want to invoke a piece of code just before the framework releases a specific (third-party) component.

I thought that I could do this by adding a delegate to `OnDestroy`, but the framework always calls `Dispose` first. (See example below).

What options do I have to invoke the code **before** `Dispose` is called?

```
public class TestClass : IDisposable
{
    static long _globalInstanceCount = 0;
    readonly long _instanceId;
    public TestClass()
    {
        _instanceId = Interlocked.Increment(ref _globalInstanceCount);
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("TestClass ({0}) - Constructor called", _instanceId));
    }
    public void ByeBye()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("TestClass ({0}) - ByeBye called", _instanceId));
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("TestClass ({0}) - Dispose called", _instanceId));
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Testing as a singleton");
            var container = new WindsorContainer()
                             .Register(Component.For<TestClass>()
                                         .LifeStyle.Singleton
                                         .OnDestroy(t => t.ByeBye())
                                       );
            TestClass tc = container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            Trace.WriteLine("Releasing the component");
            container.Release(tc);
            Trace.WriteLine("Disposing of the container");
            container.Dispose();
        }

        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Testing transient");
            var container = new WindsorContainer()
                                .Register(Component.For<TestClass>()
                                    .LifeStyle.Transient
                                    .OnDestroy(t => t.ByeBye())
                                    );
            TestClass tc = container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            Trace.WriteLine("Releasing the component");
            container.Release(tc);
            Trace.WriteLine("Disposing of the container");
            container.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

This produces the following output. As you can see, `ByeBye` is called after `Dispose`.

> Testing as a singleton
>
> TestClass (1) - Constructor called
>
> Releasing the component
>
> Disposing of the container
>
> TestClass (1) - Dispose called
>
> TestClass (1) - ByeBye called
>
> Testing transient
>
> TestClass (2) - Constructor called
>
> Releasing the component
>
> TestClass (2) - Dispose called
>
> TestClass (2) - ByeBye called
>
> Disposing of the container

I have attempted to solve this using an interceptor, but it turns out that the Windsor framework calls `Dispose` on the original component *bypassing any interceptors*.

```
            Trace.WriteLine("Testing transient with interceptor");
            var container = new WindsorContainer()
                                .Register(Component.For<TestClassInterceptor>().LifeStyle.Transient,
                                          Component.For<TestClass>()
                                                    .LifeStyle.Transient
                                                    .OnDestroy(t => t.ByeBye())
                                                    .Interceptors<TestClassInterceptor>()
                                        );
            TestClass tc = container.Resolve<TestClass>();
            tc.Hello();
            Trace.WriteLine("Releasing the component");
            container.Release(tc);
            Trace.WriteLine("Disposing of the container");
            container.Dispose();
```

Results in the following output. See that `TestClass (3) - Dispose` is called independently of the interceptor.

> Testing transient with interceptor
>
> TestClassInterceptor (1) - Constructor called
>
> TestClass (3) - Constructor called
>
> TestClassInterceptor (1) - Intecepting Method "Hello"
>
> TestClass (3) - Hello called
>
> Releasing the component
>
> TestClass (3) - Dispose called
>
> TestClassInterceptor (1) - Intecepting Method "ByeBye"
>
> TestClass (3) - ByeBye called
>
> TestClassInterceptor (1) - Dispose called
>
> Disposing of the container

Comment: HMm I guess that's a good point. It does make sense to add the `OnDestroy` action at the beginning of the pipeline. Feel free to add that as a suggestion to Windsor's YouTrack

Comment: @Krzyztof - OK, I've added this as an issue: http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-326

Comment: The YouTrack case has been exported to here: https://github.com/castleproject/castle-youtrack-export/blob/master/IOC/IOC-326.xml